# Creating models for many-to-many or foreign key

Tags: python, django, rest, model, frameworks

I have two models, `Item` and `Content`. So what I want is `Item` to have many `Content`.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.ManyToManyField('Content', blank=True)

class Content(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=255)


class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = ContentSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'content',)

class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item_id = serializer.RelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'item_id',)
```

In content serializer, note that I have given extra field `item_id`. Because I want to return the item Id the content is related to. But I'm not getting `item_id` in Content List. How do I achieve this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up your models like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
  title = CharField(max_length=255)


class Content(models.Model):
  item = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  title = CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then in your serializer **you forgot one thing, the source**:

```
class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  item_id = serializer.RelatedField(source='item', read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Content
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'item_id',)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# You need to use ForeignKey in your Item model

class Item(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='item_content')

class Content(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=255)
```